# Ruby on Rails Coffee-script-source locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, rubygems, locked

So I'm getting this error coudl not find coffee-script-source-1.8.0 in any of the sources I have alredy added `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` to my gemfile and tried `bundle update` but then it says that it's locked at 1.12.2 I go to the gemfile.lock and change `coffee-script-source (1.12.2)` to `coffee-script-source (1.8.0)` but then it gives me the error of `could not find in any of the sources` so how can I fix that error?

this is the coffee part in my gemfile.lock

`coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)`

currently using windows 10

EDIT: 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag   'default', media: 'system', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

changed `'application'` to `'default'` but i read that that's only a temporary solution to the issue and because of the default is not reading the assets at least that's what I read.

EDIT 2: Fixed it by changing `default` to `application.css` and `default` to `application.js` and deleted the `//` infront of `require turbolinks`.

Comment: Can you delete gemfile.lock and run bundle install

Comment: @Rajkumar alredy tried but if I have the `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` in the gemfile it gives the error `could not find gem 'coffee-script-source (= 1.8.0) x86-mingw32'` in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine